# iOS - Uploading image with EXIF intact

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, exif

I have images saved in my application Documents directory in .jpg format with  EXIF data. My problem is, whenever I try to convert the .jpg files into `NSData` to be uploaded using HTTP POST, the uploaded image loses all its EXIF data.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *imagePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",imageName]];
NSData *jpegImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];
```

How can I upload my .jpg files from Documents directory with their EXIF intact?

Comment: How exactly do you know that (1) the image file has the EXIF info when it's in the Documents directory and (2) the file has lost that info after uploading?

Comment: (1) I accessed the Documents directory using a file manager and copied the image out. Then using EXIF tools online to view the image EXIF.
(2) Downloaded the uploaded image again from server and used EXIF tool on it, all EXIF data is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the EXIF metadata of jpg file. I worked with the solution:

```
- (void)uploadImage:(NSString *)imagePath {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
        // Repair upload data
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imagePath];

        NSData *rawDataImage = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);

        NSString *base64EncodedString = @"";
        if ([rawDataImage respondsToSelector:@selector(base64EncodedStringWithOptions:)])
        {
            base64EncodedString = [rawDataImage base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
        }
        else
        {
            base64EncodedString = [rawDataImage base64Encoding];
        }

        NSString *uploadBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"imageData\": \"%@\"}", base64EncodedString];

        // Post uploadBody to server
        NSString *serverUrl = @"Your_server";

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:serverUrl]];

        [request addValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

        NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", uploadBody.length];
        [request addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setHTTPBody:[uploadBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:<your_delegate OR nil>];
    });
}
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: @Andrea: Yes, this solution keeps your EXIF data perfectly. I did

Comment: @phuongle Thanks for the solution, I tried to post the base64 encoded string to my server but the uploaded jpg seems to be corrupted. How do I post a base64 encoded string?

Comment: Managed to get the image upload to work. EXIF data is intact as well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What's the point of converting NSData to base64? What does it have to do with EXIF?

Comment: Hi there! I know it's an old question but does someone know how to do it today? I've done the same thing with Swift today `let rawDataImage = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)!` and `let base64String = rawDataImage.base64EncodedString(options: [])` but it did not work. I have printed the base64String to copy/paste it into my python script to convert and analyze the string but most of the EXIF data was lost like GPS information, etc. I was able to verify my python code with an online base64 converter, so the issue must be in the Swift code.